# where to put self.inheritance_column for ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

I have a question that I think I know the answer to but would like to double check.

I've encountered the

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed
```

issue that i've found a lot of good documentation on here at stack overflow and the consensus to solving this issues seems to be either :

1. don't use the word type for your table column
2. Manually set the column name to something:

   ```
    self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
   ```

since path 1 is too big of a overhaul, it makes sense to me to include this bit of code in the subclass instead of the class. Is this correct? For example:

```
MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
end

MySubclass < my_class
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
end
```

Thanks for letting me double check!

Comment: That looks like it should be fine. On a side not your class names should be constants so `MyClass` and `MySubclass` as well as you need to have the keyword `class` before the declaration such as `class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: thanks! i'll update it accordingly.